# How come i keep getting a memory leak when i run this function in my C program?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list

So basically im writing code for a linkedList, but I keep getting a memoryLeak as a result of this code here. Could anyone help me find why, and also explain to me what im doing wrong?

```c
struct Node* deleteNode(int data, struct Node* head){

    struct Node* current = head;
    struct Node* previous = NULL;

    if(head == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    while(current->data != data){
            if(current->next == NULL){
                return NULL;
            }else{
                previous = current;
                current = current->next;
            }
    }
    if(current == head){
        struct Node* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
    }else
    {
        previous->next = current->next;
    }
    current = NULL;
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never call `free()` on the deleted list node when its not the first element of your linked list.

Comment: Im sorry, im fairly new to all this. What do you mean? If im deleting a node shouldnt i free that nodes address?

Comment: @JorgeUrena You need to call `free()` on the node even in the case when `current != head`. Similar to what you did under the `if (current == head)` block.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a memory leak because you are not calling `free` in the case where `current != temp`. All you are doing in the `else` portion is simply assigning `previous->next = current->next` without deleting the current node.

You have already found the node you wish to delete using your `while` loop, so add `free(current)` after `previous->next = current->next`.